# How do I create a table without data type in oracle

Tags: oracle10g

Is it possible to create a table having column but column without datatype? Meaning is there any way to do it indirectly? If yes, then can you please give me one example.

Comment: do you mean a table without columns?

Comment: As others have said, every column must have a datatype.  But are you really looking for a generic data type that can contain anything?  If so, there are multiple options, such as XMLType, ANYDATA, and object-relational.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know only columns have data types not tables.

Do you mean a table without columns?

Or do you mean a column without a specific data type?

A little more info would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

No. Oracle columns always have a datatype, e.g. NUMBER, DATE, VARCHAR2, LOB.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has 1 such table called dual. You can select any type from dual.

[orafaq/wiki/dual](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Dual)

But it's hard to give you an exact answer. Maybe you can explain what you want to use this table for ?